# JMeter - API test Plan - Service unavailable. Please try again later error

Tags: performance-testing, api-design, jmeter-5.0

I created an API test plan in JMeter.

(Post) Login Authentication API
(Get) API to search for data (Authenticated with the help of correlation)

The Login API works fine I am able to see the response. But, the Search API is returning an error "Service unavailable.  Please try again later." with error code 500. My API request has got all the data required Can someone help me to fix the issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As per [500 Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) description:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 500 Internal Server Error server error response code indicates that **the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.**

> This error response is a generic "catch-all" response. Usually, this indicates the server cannot find a better 5xx error code to response. Sometimes, server administrators log error responses like the 500 status code with more details about the request to prevent the error from happening again in the future.

So my expectation is that you should rather check your **server logs** to figure out the root cause of the problem rather than looking for a solution from JMeter side.

In general if something is wrong with your request the server should respond with [4xx status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_client_errors)

If you have another way of sending the "search" request you can inspect it and cross check all the associated data including:

1. URL
2. [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) (can be passed via [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)), pay attention to [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) one
3. Request body
4. The value you correlated which can be checked using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination